# toolingorg.eclipse.platform.ide.config not found error while installing ADT in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

> "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software currently installed: Shared profile
>   1.0.0.1315548751860 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1315548751860)   Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1315548751860 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1315548751860) requires 'toolingorg.eclipse.platform.ide.config.win32.win32.x86_64
>   [3.7.0.I20110613-1736]' but it could not be found"

I am getting this error message while trying to install ADT in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem and what I ended up doing is going to c:\Users\UserName and deleting the .eclipse folder.

**Note: All your plugins and settings will be lost.**

Then follow the instructions for installing android. http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html